# Limit to maximum value that can be read from a file as a hex value

Tags: perl, bigint

I am using the following code to read from a file and write to another file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use bigint qw/hex/;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $defaultfile = 'C:/Users/john/Desktop/input.txt';
my $mainfile ='C:/Users/john/Desktop/output.txt';

open( my $default_fh, "<", $defaultfile ) or die $!;
open( my $main_fh,    ">", $mainfile )    or die $!;
while ( <$default_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    printf {$main_fh} "%064b\n" , hex $_;
    printf {$main_fh} "\n";
}
close $default_fh;
close $main_fh;
```

When the hex value is very large, let's say 0x0008800000000000, the corresponding binary value is wrong. But when the hex value in the source file is smaller, let's say 0x0000000088000000, then the binary output is right.

Where am I making a mistake? It seems like I need to read data into something that is capable of 64-bit data.

Comment: So I installed a 64 bit version of Perl, and this problem got solved.

Comment: @tahi, You can and should get rid of `use bigint qw/hex/;` if you switched to a Perl with 64-bit ints

Answer (score 5):

The `bigint` pragma replaces math operators with ones that return `Math:BigInt` objects, and reads numeric literals with them too. That doesn't extend to `printf`/`sprintf` formats. Things don't work out right when they try to convert from a `Math::BigInt` to a regular perl scalar integer value if the latter is too small to hold the number (It's either a 32 bit or 64 bit value depending on your OS and CPU. I'm guessing you have a 32 bit system because I get the same results with your sample numbers with bigint and regular ints on 64-bit perl; both fit in 64 bits).

Use the [`to_bin()` method](https://perldoc.pl/Math::BigInt#to_bin()) instead, and pad the resulting string:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use bigint; # Don't need to explicitly import hex in modern perl

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $num = hex $_;
    printf "%s becomes %064s\n", $_, $num->to_bin();
}

__DATA__
0x0008800000000000
0x0000000088000000
```

Comment: I tried to use your code and it said cant call method "to_bin" without a package or object reference. I added use bigint and also tried with use Math::BigInt;.

Comment: @tahi Works fine. Maybe you're using a really old version of perl (Like 5.8 or earlier) where you do need to import `hex` when using bigint. But if that's the case, you *really* need to upgrade to get the last 20 years of improvements.

Comment: The problem got solved with two steps. 1) I installed 64 bit version of PERL. 2) Secondly, this line worked: printf {$main_fh} "%064b\n" , hex $_;